# Wix 3.5 - How to add appname directory in user custom path

Tags: wix, customization, relative-path, wix3.5, sharpdevelop

i'm creating an installer using WiX and Sharpdevelop 4.4 (which uses WiX 3.5).

It's my first time using Wix, and i'm slowly getting the hang of it.

I have the following problem:

I use WixUI_Mondo as the default UI for the installer, and it suits my needs mostly fine, aside from requiring a little customization.

When the user customizes the default path to the application (such as root/pfiles/appname) i have the need to keep "/appname" directory to the new customized path (so, for example if the user chose c:\ as the custom installation path, the package is going to be installed to c:\appname).

I've tried to look around for a way to do this, and i think the key might be to edit the BrowseDlg of WixUI_Mondo, but i still haven't found a way to achieve this.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

**EDIT**

As requested in the comments, the folder structure is pretty basic:

`<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR"> 
     <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="Pfiles"> 
         <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="AppName">`

Comment: Can you share your Directory structure code?

Comment: Sure, it's just simple: `<Fragment>  
  <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">  
   <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="Pfiles">  
    <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="AppName">`

Comment: Ok, sorry, still learning how to format code in comments... i'm new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve that is to introduce a Top folder to your structure like Company\AppName e.g. SomePath\Company\AppName.

Make the INSTALLDIR the Company directory and add a static one for your AppName, then don't forget to point your components to this new Directory

Example:

```
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="Company">
                <Directory Id="Dir_App" Name="AppName"/>
```

Change your components Dir reference to Dir_App instead of INSTALLDIR

Now when you change the path in the dialog or with property through command line the change will be up to INSTALLDIR then it will create the new folder called AppName.

It might be possible to do it without introducing a top folder but will probably be trickier.

Comment: Already tried this. The problem is that the UI doesn't show the full path so, even if the custom path is set by the user to C:\ and installs to c:\appname, the user see c:\ and thinks that the application will install in C:\ and eventually he might edit it adding another directory so the end result is c:\userdir\appname. I want to avoid this showing c:\appname during the UI editing. Or it might be that i'm missing something.

Comment: I think i understand what you mean, that the path displayed in the UI is misleading if you add another folder underneath INSTALLDIR and solution to that i don't know.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem i'm having. The user doesn't see the underlying folder in the ui and thinks it doesn't exists.